# Upgrading from t2.micro to t2.medium keep current Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, upgrade

I'm running a t2.micro on AWS. I guess most are who take the 750h free server, so it needs a bit more power and I'm thinking perhaps update, and I spent some time looking at the forum. It looks like the update is easy as in make image/snapshot close server start new at higher tier add things back.

But all the answers also list that you lose your public IP, and I have a few things that now hardcoded to the public IP some that I'm not easily able to get access to.

I see the Elastic IPs solves the problem, but only if you used it from the start so just want to know for sure if 100% not possible to keep current public IP but move to t2.medium

Thanks for any feedback that might help

Comment: it's best just to take the short pain and change everything for the better.  you can get the dynamic public ip via api but i guess in your case its just best to maybe use eip. and maybe even hang an additional dns/lb in front of it and use that.  LB even if you use only one node.  you might also consider 2 smaller instead of one bigger machine. depends on your requirements.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, you're kinda stuck here. You may be able to temporarily scale a bit by turning on "unlimited bursting" for the `t2.micro`, as that'll let it burst above its limits indefinitely (at a cost to you). Use that while you track down the hard-coded IPs and replace them with an elastic IP or (preferably) a DNS hostname under your control.

Comment: Yep, I get the feeling I need to face it,  guess its possible, but then they can't sell the e-ip solution  thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to upgrade you will lose your public ip. you may keep original instance with your IP and configure it as internet gateway in the VPC. so its IP will be the public address.
you will give the new instance private IP only and then add desired route, 
don't forget to configure your original instance:

`sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: Thanks, Sadly the current setup is not a Linux setup software did not give me that option .. but thanks

Comment: if you are using windows instance just enable internet connection sharing
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/internet-connection-sharing-in-windows-10/f6dcac4b-5203-4c98-8cf2-dcac86d98fb9

Comment: I get what you saying but not how it affects my ability to AWS to scale and keep public IP,